# Random variable to the power of minus one?

Tags: probability, random-variables

I have a definition, it goes as follows:

$\Pr$ is probability. $X$ is a random variable.

$x\in\mathbb{R}$

$$Pr(X = x) = \Pr(\{ \omega\in\Omega \mid X(\omega)=x\})$$

So for example for a dice of 6 sides if $x=5$, then $\Pr(X=5)=\frac{1}{6}$ , if we ordered to every side of the dice the corresponding integer.

They say then:

$$Pr(X = x) = \Pr(X^{-1}(x))$$

What does this mean? Cause as I understand it, it is reciproc of 5, times 5, that is one, it makes no sense...

Could anyone please tell me what they mean with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means inverse set. If you have a probability space, $(\Omega, \Sigma, P)$ and a random variable $X \colon \Omega \to \Bbb{R}$, then $P(X=x)=P(\{\omega \in \Omega \colon X(\omega)=x\})=P(X^{-1}(x))$.

The latter set is DEFINED as

$$X^{-1}(x)\colon =\{\omega \in \Omega \colon X(\omega)=x\}$$

$X^{-1}(x)$ is a set.

For example if you have a random variable for a coin flip, say $X(h)=1$ and $X(t)=-1$. Then $X^{-1}(1)=\{h\}$ and $X^{-1}(-1)=\{t\}$. This is a slight abuse of notation. It would probably be better to write:

$X^{-1}(\{1\})=\{h\}$ and $X^{-1}(\{-1\})=\{t\}$

Also $P(X=1)=P(\{\omega \in \Omega \colon X(\omega)=1\})=P(\{h\})=\frac12$

Comment: Hi. I don't get it fully yet, $X$ is not a set, yet $X^{-1}$ is a set, and an inverse? inverse of what?

Comment: @user3435407 You are correct, $X$ is not a set. $X$ is a random variable. $X^{-1}(\{x\})$, written with abuse of notation as $X^{-1}(x)$ is the INVERSE SET of $\{x\}$.

Comment: does it here matter if X was injective or not?

Comment: @user3435407 No. Like I said, it's an inverse SET. So for example the constant random variable where $X(\omega) = 5$ for all $\omega$ in some probability space. Then $X^{-1}(5)=\Omega$.

Comment: Ok, thanks, now I see, I just couldn't find a definition for an inverse set, and I connected it to inverse of a function.